# Getting error while making Google Translation App

Tags: google-translate

I'm trying to make the Google Translate App using Google jar file. I have added external .jar files called **google-api-translate-java-0.97** into my android project.

My code is as following

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    String text;
    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
         
         try
        {
             TranslateV2.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/");
            text = Translate.DEFAULT.execute("hello", Language.ENGLISH, Language.MARATHI);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (GoogleAPIException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Im getting errors as below:

- Could not find method com.google.api.translate.TranslateV2.setHttpReferrer, referenced from method com.example.translator.MainActivity.onCreate
- java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/translator/MainActivity

**Please help me to make successful translator App using another method if your have any.**

Comment: Can you try the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#java-install to see if it will work?

Comment: I have tried this solution recently but getting more and more errors due to this statement : **compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.14.0'**. as Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties